# How to merge two arrays using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var tempStoreFood = [];
var sameFoodID = [];
var differentFoodID = [];
var finalStoreFood = [];

console.log("Temporary stored food", tempStoreFood);
console.log("Same Food Group", sameFoodID);
console.log("Different Food Group", differentFoodID);
console.log("Concatenate");

for (i = 0; i < self.foods.length; i++) {
  var foodBrand = self.foods[i];
  var foodBrandID = self.foods[i].brand_id;
  tempStoreFood.push(foodBrand);
  for (j = 0; j < tempStoreFood.length; j++) {
    var foodID = tempStoreFood[j].brand_id;
    var singleFood = tempStoreFood[j];
    if (foodID == foodBrandID) {
      sameFoodID.push(singleFood);
      break;
    }
    if (foodID !== foodBrandID) {
      differentFoodID.push(singleFood);
      break;
    }
  }
```

[image: out put of the code]

from the output i have got the samefoodID array and different food id array. now i want to group it as this(final output). 
any idea how can i do this using javascript.

[image: final output]

Comment: Your screenshots don't show any details about what is actually in your arrays. Post your input and expected output in your question, not as images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Answer (score 1):

You can use .concat() method

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var array3 = array1.concat(array2);

console.log(array3);
```

Comment: [Use this link for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var sameFoodID = [1,2,3];
var differentFoodID = [4,5];
var mergeResult = [...sameFoodID,...differentFoodID];

console.log(mergeResult);
```

The spread operator is a useful and quick syntax for adding items to arrays, combining arrays or objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting the final output as an array like,

```
arrayMergedFood = array(arraySameFood, arrayDifferentFood)
```

then create a new array arrayMergedFood, then push the array arraySameFood and arrayDifferentFood on to that array. Avoid mutation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread operator to merge array.

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
var arr2 = [ ...arr1, 5,6,7,8]
console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although using the `spread` operator in combination with `push` or `splice` is terse and efficient, you will run into `stack overflow` errors for large arrays.

So if your data set is expected to be large, either:

1. Always use `concat`.
2. Check the size and then conditionally either use the `spread` operator with `push` or `splice`, or `concat` for larger arrays.

```js
const data1 = Array(1_000).fill('X')
const data2 = Array(1_000_000).fill('X')

// Spread will work, but only up to a certain size
try {
  const target = []
  target.push(...data1)
  console.log(target.length)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}

// Spread will fail
try {
  const target = []
  target.push(...data2)
  console.log(target.length)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}

// Concat will work
try {
  const target = []
  const newTarget = target.concat(data2)
  console.log(newTarget.length)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}

// safeConcat will work
try {
  const target = []
  const maybeNewTarget = safeConcat(target, data2)
  console.log(maybeNewTarget.length)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}

// A safe concat that uses the faster spread operator.
function safeConcat(items, data) {
  // Max items will depend on your runtime
  if (data.length < 500_000) {
    items.push(...data)
    return items
  } else {
    return items.concat(data)
  }
}
```